# Copy file from PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to copy some file from source directory to target directory by a script.
The condition is the new file supposed to come everyday at some certain time. My scripts is checking the pattern of the file name and check the dates if greater than today's date (00:00:00) then copying it. But its working fine if latest date's file is available on next morning then copy that file. But if the latest file is not available then it copying all the other files from that source directory. Can anyone check my script and tell me what's wrong in it?

```
$fromDir = "\\fil\folder\path\files" 

$destinationMask = Join-Path "C:\XXX\ABCD_K_Integration\F_datafiles" "{0}.kis.txt" 
    
$files = Get-ChildItem $fromDir `
    | where Name -match "ALMR12_\d+.txt" `
    | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } `
    | where LastWriteTime -gt (get-date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0)
    
# copy file 
Get-ChildItem $fromDir -filter "$files" | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Copy-Item -Dest {"$destinationMask" -f $_.BaseName}
```

This is my source file list.

[image]

You can see last file came on 30th, which means if i run my job it is copying all the files, but if i create a 0 byte file with todays date for testing then my script is working properly. Can't understand what's wrong in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Tested following and it works fine for me. Nothing is copied if no file fullfils the filter

```
$fromDir = "path_from_folder" 
$toDir = "path_to_folder"
   
Get-ChildItem $fromDir |
    Where-Object {($_.Name -match "ALMR12_\d+.txt") -and `
        (! $_.PSIsContainer) -and `
        ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0))
    } |
    Copy-Item -Destination $toDir
```

Comment: You don't need backticks. And `Get-ChildItem` has the paramter `-File`. So no need to use `(! $_.PSIsContainer)`. 

Comment: Indeed no need to backtick, it for sole readability

Comment: How does that increase the readablity?   Actually it is very much error prone. If you accidentally add a space behind it it'll break your code and it is hard to see why.

Comment: Using `(Get-Date).Date` will produce the date with a time of 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to filter the files twice, `$files` should contain the files you're after. In fact, filtering by `"$files"` in the second Get-ChildItem would fail if the variable contains more than one single file.

If you replace this line

```
Get-ChildItem $fromDir -filter "$files" | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Copy-Item -Dest {"$destinationMask" -f $_.BaseName}
```

with the following it'll probably work.

```
$files | Copy-Item -Dest { "$destinationMask" -f $_.BaseName } -WhatIf
```

Please note that I added `-WhatIf` to the command to avoid any accidental file copies - remove it after you've tested it.

Comment: Instead of `where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }` you could use the paramter `-File` for the cmdlet `Get-ChildItem` 

Comment: Yeah, that's a comment for the original question really but I hear you.